# What should the URL be for Readiness and Liveness Probe Endpoints?

Tags: url, kubernetes, health-monitoring, kubernetes-health-check

Should I use URL's at the root of my application like so:

```
/ready
/live
```

Should they both be grouped together like so:

```
/status/ready
/status/live
```

Should I use [RFC5785](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785) and put them under the `.well-known` sub-directory like so:

```
/.well-known/status/ready
/.well-known/status/live
```

If I do this, my understanding is that I have to register the `status` assignment with the official [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/well-known-uris/well-known-uris.xhtml) registry.

Or is there some other scheme? I'm looking for a common convention that people use.

Answer (score 4):

The Kubernetes docs use `/healthz`, which I'd say is advisable to follow; but you really can use whatever you want.

I believe `healthz` is used to keep it inline with `zpages`, which are described by OpenCensus:

https://opencensus.io/zpages/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can use whatever you want and it's whatever you put in your application. If you have a way in your application to differentiate between "Ready" and "Alive". Either one of these using a GET request works:

```
/ready
/live
```

or

```
/status/ready
/status/live
```

Note that generally 'alive' means that your app has come up and 'ready' means that your app is ready to serve traffic.